# Printing a double half pyramid in C

Tags: c

I want to print two half pyramids that look like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yze8MlI.png]

so far my code looks something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int row, star, space, n;
    printf("Enter row number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        for (space = n - 1; space >= row; space--){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (star = 1; star <= row; star++) {
            printf("##");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it prints the whole pyramid,how do I implement a space in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height=5;
    const char* bricks = "###############"
    for(int i=1; i<height+1; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s      %.*s\n", height,i,bricks, i,bricks);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEOne Link](http://ideone.com/i5jtEJ)

Output:

```
    #      #
   ##      ##
  ###      ###
 ####      ####
#####      #####
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(star=1;star<=row*2;star++){

        printf("#");
    if(star == row)
    printf(" ");

 }
```

**Modify the second loop as above**

Answer (score 0):

The following code is **simple to understand** and **gives you full control** over the peramid:

You can change also the height (number of rows) and the size of the half peramid (in example - 4). Then it prints `*` as the bricks in the image, `spaces` as the spaces and `##` as the space between them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int row,col,space,n1=4, n2=4;

    for(row=1;row<=n1;row++){

    for(space=n2-row;space>=0;space--)
        printf(" ");

    for(col=1;col<=row;col++)
        printf("*");

    printf("##");

    for(col=1;col<=row;col++)
        printf("*");      

    for(space=n2-row;space>=0;space--)
        printf(" ");

    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

**Example output:**

```
    *##*    
   **##**   
  ***##***  
 ****##****
```